# issue.getComments() is empty using Jira API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I am using Jira API to get issue from jira, when i try to get the comments of an issue the iterable list is always empty

```
Iterator<Comment> comments = issue.getComments().iterator();

while (comments.hasNext()){
        Comment comment = comments.next();
        System.out.println("Comment : " + comment.getBody() + " by " + comment.getAuthor().getDisplayName());
}
```

I've try with postman and the  `GET` return comments in `JSON`

Why ?

Comment: everything is returned in json by default, so not only the comments.

Comment: The get is here only to check if really there is a comment but the quesrion is why the get comment isn t retreiving comment

Comment: It is getting the comment, the comment is inside the JSON, you should recognize it if you inspect the json more closely.

Comment: @Runningriot the `issue.getComments().iterator()` is empty i've tried